# A Node.js app on Heroku requires a 'package.json' at the root of the directory structure

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm trying to upload my api to the web, and I heard that 'Heroku' is a good free cloud platform. I **do** have package.json:
[image: the root folder]

Build Log:

```
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/nodejs.tgz

 !     ERROR: Application not supported by 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack
 !     
 !     The 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack is set on this application, but was
 !     unable to detect a Node.js codebase.
 !         
 !     A Node.js app on Heroku requires a 'package.json' at the root of
 !     the directory structure.
 !     
 !     If you are trying to deploy a Node.js application, ensure that this
 !     file is present at the top level directory. This directory has the
 !     following files:
 !     
 !     Bezeq.js
 !     Cellcom.js
 !     Hot.js
 !     MainAPI.js
 !     node_modules/
 !     package-lock.json
 !     Partner.js
 !         
 !     If you are trying to deploy an application written in another
 !     language, you need to change the list of buildpacks set on your
 !     Heroku app using the 'heroku buildpacks' command.
 !         
 !     For more information, refer to the following documentation:
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#activation
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed
```

Why doesn't it work?
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure `package.json` is properly committed? Can you post the exact Heroku log?

Comment: Please be a lot more clear about what you're doing and what "doesn't work" means. See [ask].

Comment: I've added the full build log, thank you

Comment: Also as a side not, as it seems your package.json is not properly committed.  Generally it is good practice to add node_modules to .gitignore it is unneeded bloat, because that is what package.json is for.  There is no need for it in your repository

Comment: Your `package.json` isn't committed, as shown in the error message. (`package-lock.json` is, and it should be, but you should include the `package.json` too. And Aidan is right: `node_modules/` shouldn't be included. Run `git rm -r --cached node_modules`, then commit. Add your `package.json` in a commit. Then deploy again.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you run "npm init" at the root of your project to create package.json ?

Comment: At the beginning no, It just was there for some reason :)
But then I read that you need to run npm init to create package.json so I deleted my original file and ran npm init. Unfortunately it's still giving me errors

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it, the problem was as expected - in the 'package.json' file.
I ran 'npm init' but this time more carefully and noticed the little details.
After that, I tried again to deploy and it worked.
Thank You Ali for the direction

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue but my solution was related to a different problem I think someone else might benefit from.
The push has to be either on your main branch or branch:main

```
git push heroku <your_branch>:main
```